# Python 3 urllib.request data struggles

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

Can anyone explain me why 'version 1' of my code doesn't work and 'version 2' does?
Output of both versions are below. For some reason the `my_data` is incorrectly inserted in the urllib request but I cannot figure out why. I tried 20 different examples and methods also straight from Python documentation but it's no bueno. It's not only the 'action' key, also when i want to insert the username and password as keys it's no success. Scratching my brain here...

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import urllib.parse

my_url = 'http://{0}:{1}/?username=myuser&password=mypass'.format('10.10.127.47', 80)
my_headers = { "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }

# ---- begin version 1 / not working ----------------------------------------------
my_data = { "action" : "getmetadata" }       
my_uedata = urllib.parse.urlencode(my_data)
my_edata = my_uedata.encode('utf-8')                
req = urllib.request.Request(url=my_url, data=my_edata, headers=my_headers)
# ---- end version 1 --------------------------------------------------------------

# ---- begin version 2 / works fine -----------------------------------------------
req = urllib.request.Request(url=''.join([my_url, '&action=getmetadata']), data=None, headers=my_headers)
# ---- end version 2 --------------------------------------------------------------

response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
html = response.read()
print(html)
```

Version 1 output:

```
b'{"schemaVersion":"3.0.0","action":"Unknown","actionDetail":null,"userName":"myuser","password":"mypass","metadata":[],"configurations":[],"commandItems":[]}'
```

Version 2 output:

```
b'{"schemaVersion":"3.0.0","action":"GetMetadata","actionDetail":null,"userName":"myuser","password":"mypass","metadata":[{"key":"permissions","value":[]},{"key":"Title","value":"Blabla"},{"key":"Description","value":"fjshkfsdhskjhfsk"},{"key":"Keyword","value":""},{"key":"Learningdescription","value":""},{"key":"Rightsdescription","value":"Creative Commons"},{"key":"SessionId","value":""},{"key":"PauseAndResumeVideoTime","value":""},{"key":"VideoSegments","value":""},{"key":"VideoTrackPosition","value":"0,25:50,75;50,25:100,75"},{"key":"SlideTrackPositionIndex","value":"2"},{"key":"Coverage","value":""},{"key":"Language","value":"en"},{"key":"Structure","value":"linear"},{"key":"Aggregationlevel","value":"3"},{"key":"SubjectAreas","value":"NBC1"},{"key":"Version","value":"1.0"},{"key":"Status","value":"final"},{"key":"EducationalLearningResourceType","value":"informatiebron"},{"key":"intendedenduserrole","value":"learner"},{"key":"EducationalContext","value":"HBO"},{"key":"Typicalagerange","value":"18-24"},{"key":"Difficulty","value":"medium"},{"key":"Typicallearningtime","value":""},{"key":"EducationalLanguage","value":"en"},{"key":"Cost","value":"No"},{"key":"Copyrights","value":"Yes"},{"key":"Showincatalogue","value":"True"},{"key":"PublishDate","value":""},{"key":"ExpirationTime","value":"730"},{"key":"Duration","value":"0"},{"key":"contributors","value":[]}],"configurations":[],"commandItems":[]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the first version you're specifying a payload that is to be sent, but eventually is not used, since `urllib.request.Request` assumes `GET` as default method, which does not include any body. If you'd like to send the payload, please specify as constructor argument `method='POST'`, which will allow the server to read the body of your request.

In the second scenario, you're passing the payload as URL parameters, which are normally recognized by `GET` method.

For reference, please see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request).

Comment: Thanks but tried it, no bueno still. Same output as Version 1. :(

Comment: Are you sure that the server even supports POST queries? It's possible, that it only supports GET method, so the first version would not be suitable in any way.

Comment: Good question! It's perfectly possible it doesn't support it but it's some 3rd party software so I need to make some calls. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried it with Postman using a POST request and it works fine in there too. So I am really baffled what I am doing wrong in Python.

Comment: When setting `method=POST` are you still urlencoding `my_data`? If positive, there's the issue. Just leave `my_data` as it is and send it along with `POST` request, setting `data=my_data`.

Comment: When I do it without encoding, I get error messages that it needs bytes to Post. But it's fine for now, I will just concatenate the url string by using params and get the info that way. Thanks.